# Is there any way in google cloud to automatically erase a past docker image the moment you create a new one?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, docker-image

I made a google cloud run trigger that creates an image the moment you make a git push into the repo. This creates the image that is stored in gc, but in the long run that will be full of docker images. I´m lookin for a way to do it automatically, i know it can be done manually but that is not what I want. Anything is helpful at this moment

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate your code in Cloud Source Repositories. Then, Cloud Build will create the desired Docker image than will be pushed to Google Cloud Container Registry. As soon as you commit code, the whole pipeline will run, updating the image.

Click the Cloud Run instance / Set up continuous deployment, enter the GitHub repo and enter Build configuration.

Then you attach the existing Cloud Build trigger to Cloud Run service

GCP Documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build

Comment: the problem is my pipeline is already done, it works and all, but i wanted to knowhow to auto erase images